# Recover recycle bin data when deleted data exceeds the bin capacity

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, recycle-bin

My recycle bin was empty. I deleted the 6 GB of data but when I restoring it I get only 4 Gb. How can I recover the 2 GB ??

Comment: You need to use generic [data-recovery](http://superuser.com/search?q=data+recovery) procedures. Also, make sure to set the [Recycle Bin limit](http://i.stack.imgur.com/caEDx.png) high enough to accommodate whatever you want to delete.

Answer (score 2):

Recover from a backup. If the data wasn't important enough to back up when it was easy, it's definitely not worth elaborate heroic measures.